# Error when including a contact to group using People API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I need to add a single contact to all the below groups. I tried to add the contact to groups one by one, however when I tested with the first group the API gave an error

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to people.contactGroups.members.modify failed with error: Cannot add contacts to deprecated system contact group resource name "contactGroups/chatBuddies".

I want to add the created contact to all these groups

- contactGroups/chatBuddies
- contactGroups/all
- contactGroups/friends
- contactGroups/coworkers
- contactGroups/family
- contactGroups/blocked

I dont see anywhere that these groups are depreciated

I have tried with

```
var b = {
    "phoneNumbers": [{
        "type": "mobile",
        "value": "09876543210"
    }],
    "names": [{
        "unstructuredName": "Test account"
    }],
    "urls": [],
    "addresses": [{
        "type": "work",
        "formattedValue": "0"
    }],
    "organizations": [{
        "name": "Organisation"
    }],
    "emailAddresses": [{
        "type": "home",
        "value": "abcd@gmail.com"
    }]
}

function doGet(e) {
    var resource = People.People.createContact(b);
    var id = resource.metadata.sources[0].id;
    var contactResourceName = resource["resourceName"];
    var group = People.ContactGroups.get("contactGroups/friends");
    var groupResourceName = group["resourceName"];
    var membersResource = {
        "resourceNamesToAdd": [
            contactResourceName
        ]
    }
    People.ContactGroups.Members.modify(membersResource, groupResourceName);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(group));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Where was the deprecation notice?**

> It was on display in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying "Beware of the Leopard."

In all seriousness, advanced services are thin layers wrapping the corresponding REST APIs, in this case, [People API](https://developers.google.com/people?hl=en), therefore each method of the service has a corresponding method exposed by the API, specifically [`contactGroups.members.modify`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups.members/modify?hl=en).

The description of the method reads as follows, clearly outlining that system contact groups are, in fact, deprecated:

> The only system contact groups that can have members added are contactGroups/myContacts and contactGroups/starred. Other system contact groups are deprecated and can only have contacts removed.

---

**Can I update system groups via the API directly?**

It does not seem to be possible, as adding system groups to contact when updating `memberships` field via the [`people.updateContact`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact) method is explicitly forbidden (you have to examine the [`ContactGroupMembership`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.ContactGroupMembership) resource docs to find the info):

> Any contact group membership can be removed, but only user group or "myContacts" or "starred" system group memberships can be added.