# adding contact to existing group (people api migration)

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to get all this stuff migrated from the much simpler Contact API before it's switched before it's switched off in a few days. I'm able to add people now, but adding them to the group that is shared company wide isn't working.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095816/add-a-created-contact-to-a-group-by-people-api-using-google-apps-script
function createContactLead(lead) {

  var contactResource = {
    "names": [{
      "displayNameLastFirst": lead["FirstName"] + " " + lead["LastName"],
      "familyName": lead["LastName"],
      "givenName" : lead["FirstName"]
    }],
    "phoneNumbers": [{
      'value': lead["Phone"],
      'type' : 'mobile',
    }],
    "emailAddresses": [{
      'value': lead["Email"]
    }],
    "addresses": [{
      "city": lead["city"],
      "region": lead["state"]
    }],
  }


  var peopleResource = People.People.createContact(contactResource);
  var contactResourceName = peopleResource["resourceName"];

  groupName = "Leads (Shared)";
  var groups = People.ContactGroups.list()["contactGroups"];
  var group = groups.find(group => group["name"] === groupName);

  console.log(group);

  var groupResourceName = group["resourceName"];
  console.log("group resource name %s", groupResourceName);

  var membersResource = {
    "resourceNamesToAdd": [
      contactResourceName
    ]
  }
  People.ContactGroups.Members.modify(membersResource, groupResourceName);
}
```

It definitely finds the group but trying to modify it results in " Invalid value at 'resource_names_to_add' (resource_names_to_add), Starting an object on a scalar field"

```
Execution log
12:34:02 PM Notice  Execution started
12:34:03 PM Info    { formattedName: 'Leads (Shared)',
  groupType: 'USER_CONTACT_GROUP',
  metadata: { updateTime: '2021-02-08T17:56:34.066Z' },
  name: 'Leads (Shared)',
  memberCount: 89,
  etag: 'XadlO6et7QY=',
  resourceName: 'contactGroups/27ee381f0e7d94e7' }
12:34:03 PM Info    group resource name contactGroups/27ee381f0e7d94e7
12:34:03 PM Error   
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to people.contactGroups.members.modify failed with error: Invalid value at 'resource_names_to_add' (resource_names_to_add), Starting an object on a scalar field
createContactLead   @ test.gs:41
driver  @ test.gs:68
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had a bug early on where I wasn't pulling out the "resourceName" from the people object. The code has since been updated in the question. Once that was fixed everything worked. I'll leave this up as it wasn't easy to get right.

Comment: Why  not go ahead and make it an answer.  It might be helpful to someone.

Comment: @Cooper I did fix the code in the original post but I did not state that in my answer. Fixing now.